# Why using DirectCast assigning Excel Objects

Tags: vb.net, excel-interop, directcast

I am struggeling with understanding the following code

```
Dim _xlsSheet As Excel.Worksheet = DirectCast(xlworkbook.Worksheets(Name), Excel.Worksheet)
```

or

```
xlworkbook = DirectCast(xlApp.ActiveWorkbook, Excel.Workbook)
```

All examples I work throu concerning Excel.Interop I see the use of DirectCast everywhere. what i dont understand is why we have to use DirectCast here. If I declare `dim xlworkbook as excel.workbook` have using directcast instead of just assigning the workbook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `xlworkbook.Worksheets()` method returns an `Excel.Sheets` collection. Collections (normally) return items of type `Object`, and as such, they should be cast to the type you are expecting.

As for the `xlworkbook = DirectCast(xlApp.ActiveWorkbook, Excel.Workbook)`, it appears this `DirectCast` may not be needed, unless the xlApp was created without a reference using `CreateObject("Excel.Application")`, which would create an object instead.